# GCP from trial to normal transition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing, google-cloud-billing

I started a free trial account on GCP with card authorization. I got my 300$ of resources. I want to use more than 8 cores though, so from what I understand I have to upgrade to a normal account. The thing I don't know is

Will credits gained from free trial be still available on my account after switching to the normal account? Or will I lose all the money given by Google?

Answer (score 1):

Earlier answers are now outdated. As of August 17, 2020 new terms state that "users now have 90 days to use their $300 USD in Google Cloud credits." After 90 days any unused credits will expire.

Also note: "If Customer upgrades to the standard Google Cloud Platform account before the Free Trial ends, any unused credit will continue to apply and will *expire 3 months after the Free Trial Start Date* if it remains unused." Therefore the period is now reduced to 3 months instead of 12, but you will still have any free credits remaining for that period.

For full details please see Supplemental Terms and Conditions For Google Cloud Platform Free Trial which can be found at https://cloud.google.com/terms/free-trial

Answer (score 0):

As per the [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#credit-when-upgrading):

> If you upgrade to a paid account before the 12-month trial period ends, any remaining amount of your initial $300 credit remains in your account.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for my oversight